# pass parameters to custom view android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add a calendar to my app. I use for it a custom view
I want to add events to the calendar from a database. I need to pass a string to the custom view so it will know from where to retrieve the data. I didn't find how to do it.

```
package com.example.homerunner;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class CoachCalendarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CustomCalendarView customCalendarView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_coach_calendar);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String uid = intent.getStringExtra("uid");
        Log.d("Loge", "onCreate: " + uid);

        customCalendarView = (CustomCalendarView)findViewById(R.id.custom_calender_view);
    }
}
```

the string that I want to pass is saved in `String uid = intent.getStringExtra("uid");`

the custom View code

```
public class CustomCalendarView extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, EventRecyclerAdapter.OnEventListener {

    Context context;

    public CustomCalendarView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomCalendarView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        this.context = context;

    }

    public CustomCalendarView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add a setter to your view.

Comment: Have a look at this https://applandeo.com/blog/material-calendar-view-customized-calendar-widget-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most simple things that you can do is to add a setter method in your custom view class, then use this setter to pass the value you want to the custom view.

For example, you can do the following:

```java
public class CustomCalendarView extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, EventRecyclerAdapter.OnEventListener {

    Context context;
    //note the new filed added!
    private String uid;

    public CustomCalendarView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomCalendarView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        this.context = context;

    }

    public CustomCalendarView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    //note the new setter added!
    public void setUid(String uid){
        this.uid = uid;
    }

}
```

Then, from the activity, you can simply do the following:

```java
package com.example.homerunner;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class CoachCalendarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CustomCalendarView customCalendarView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_coach_calendar);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String uid = intent.getStringExtra("uid");
        Log.d("Loge", "onCreate: " + uid);

        customCalendarView = (CustomCalendarView)findViewById(R.id.custom_calender_view);

        //note the setter usage!
        customCalendarView.setUid(uid);
    }
}
```

And now the custom view has the uid you need to sent it.

Comment: I tried to do what you said. I added the Setter.
```public CustomCalendarView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    this.context = context;
Toast.makeText(context, this.uid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
``` it did an empty toast

Comment: You can't use the value that you in the contractor, you need to use it **after** you set the value. The following example will show the toast with the uid.
`public void setUid(String uid){
        this.uid = uid;
        Toast.makeText(context, this.uid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }`

Comment: Can I do that the view will be shown only after I set the uid?

Comment: Ok great that it's working. :)
But I don't understand your last question, can you explain it more?

Comment: I found a solution to my question.